# Python: variable bindings in recursive functions

Tags: python, function, recursion, python-bindings

I came across some weirdness in Python using a function similar to the following:

```
    def foo(x):
        if int(x)!=4:
            x = raw_input("Wrong guess, please enter new value: " )
            foo(x)
        else:
            print "Good Job! %s was right"%x
        return x

    value = foo(x=raw_input("Guess a Number between 1 and 10: "))
    print value
```

If I enter, for instance: "1" then "2" then "3" then "4", I get the following printed out:

```
Good Job! 4 was right
2
```

This is confusing, since it seems the function is successfully identifying the right answer, but after doing so it is returning a value that was the 2nd response given, instead of the most recent response.

Can anyone explain what's going on with the binding of "x" in this recursive function?

Comment: Related: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see!

```
value = foo(raw_input())
# foo is the same as in the question, I won't repeat it here
print value
```

Inside your foo, you get this:

```
# foo(1) calls foo(2) and sets x to 2
# foo(2) calls foo(3) and sets x to 3
# foo(3) calls foo(4) and sets x to 4
# foo(4) does:
print "Good Job! 4 was right"
return 4 # to foo(3)
# foo(3) does:
return 4 # to foo(2)
# foo(2) does:
return 3 # to foo(1)
# foo(1) does:
return 2 # to main
```

Since the return value to main (from the outermost recursion) is `2`, that's what `value` remains.

To fix this, you can either make it iterative:

```
def iter_foo(x):
    while int(x) != 4:
        x = raw_input("Wrong guess. Try again! ")
    print "Good Job! %s was right" % x
    return x
```

Or make EACH recursion return the result of the new function

```
def recurse_foo(x):
    if int(x) != 4:
        return foo(raw_input("Wrong guess. Try again! "))
    else:
        print "Good Job! %s was right!" % x
        return x
```

Comment: Accepting this for the two workarounds provided, and a good explanation of how the foo() executions call each other.  The other answers are helpful too, I now understand how the recursive calls are working

Answer (score 3):

So it's mostly because you are missing a `return` in

```
def foo(x):
    if int(x)!=4:
        x = raw_input("Wrong guess, please enter new value: " )
        foo(x) # <-- need return
    else:
        print "Good Job! %s was right"%x
    return x

value = foo(x=raw_input("Guess a Number between 1 and 10: "))
print value
```

What's happening is it calls `foo(1)`, which is not equal to 4, assigns `x` to 2, and that is the last value that `x` gets assigned to, so

- Your recursive `foo(x)` returns a value, but it isn't assigned to anything or returned from the recursive call.
- The last value `x` received was 2, so that is what the initial `foo(1)` returns

So either

```
x = foo(x)
```

Or

```
return foo(x)
```

On the line I highlighted

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
def foo(x):
    if int(x)!=4:
        x = raw_input("Wrong guess, please enter new value: " )
        return foo(x)
    else:
        print "Good Job! %s was right"%x
        return x

value = foo(x=raw_input("Guess a Number between 1 and 10: "))
print value
```

You can think each call to the function foo, creates a new variable x. Thus, the recursive calls make a sequence of variables x1, x2, x3, etc. Thus when a function call returns, your local variable x is unchanged. That's why you still get 2 instead of the assignment from the last recursive call (4). If you want to change the variable passed into a function, you need to pass it by reference (or object), rather than by value. [See this article for more details: http://uvesway.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/passing-arguments-to-a-function-by-value-by-reference-by-object/]

Comment: You probably should mention that, as Python does not have [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), using recursion here could lead to stack overflow.